# How to send an aspx page which contain graphs using email

Tags: c#, asp.net

My aspx page contain some drop down and graphs ,when i am try to send it,it's working fine but in recieved email it doesn't include graphs and selected drop down items.Please help me

here is my code..

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //create the mail message
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

        //set the addresses
        mail.From = new MailAddress("vprajapat@nvidia.com");
        mail.To.Add("vprajapat@nvidia.com");

        //set the content
        mail.Subject = "This is an email";

        //screen scrape the html
        string html = ScreenScrapeHtml("http://localhost:60275/WebSite5/Default2.aspx");
        mail.Body = html;
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

        //send the message
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.nvidia.com", 25);
        //smtp.EnableSsl = true;

        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        smtp.Send(mail);
    }
    public static string ScreenScrapeHtml(string url)
    {
        WebRequest objRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(objRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
        string result = sr.ReadToEnd();
        sr.Close();
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

what about page.RenderControl() or control.RenderControl()..?

System.Web.UI

```
 Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
 Dim sw As New StringWriter(sb)
 Dim htw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
 gridview.RenderControl(htw)  // or (control you wish)
 Dim str As String = sb.ToString()
```

plz convert into c#

Comment: can you please provide more about these means how to use them..namespace for them etc?

Answer (score 0):

you may make this trick :

make HTML page contains Only `<iframe>` element and it's `source` the page you want to be displayed in the email

keep in mind this trick doesn't work with all mail providers companies , there is a list of them you must check them first before using this trick : http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3219/do-iframes-work-in-email/